# Postgresql 10 unable to insert into table with identity primary key

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, identity, postgresql-10

I have the following table called timesheet.

```
 Table "public.timesheet"
       Column        |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |           Default            
---------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------
 timesheetid         | integer                |           | not null | generated always as identity
 employeeid          | integer                |           |          | 
 date_linkid         | integer                |           |          | 
 employee_functionid | integer                |           |          | 
 start_time          | time without time zone |           |          | 
 finish_time         | time without time zone |           |          | 
 note                | text                   |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "timesheet_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (timesheetid)
Check constraints:
    "timesheet_time_check" CHECK (finish_time > start_time)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "timesheet_date_linkid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (date_linkid) REFERENCES date_link(date_linkid)
    "timesheet_employee_functionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (employee_functionid) REFERENCES employee_function(employee_functionid)
    "timesheet_employeeid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES employee(employeeid)
```

When I run the following command:

```
--INSERT TIMESHEET INFORMATION:
INSERT INTO timesheet (timesheetid,employeeid,date_linkid,employee_functionid,start_time,finish_time,note)
VALUES

        (DEFAULT,1,223,1,'13:56:00','16:40:00',NULL),
        (DEFAULT,1,223,3,'18:10:00','18:19:00',NULL)
;
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  cannot insert into column "timesheetid"
DETAIL:  Column "timesheetid" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
HINT:  Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
```

I have no clue where I am going wrong, because I tried it again after executing the following commands and still end up with the same error message. Anyone know what is going wrong here?

```
crewdb=# SELECT MAX(timesheetid) FROM timesheet;
 max 
-----
 418
(1 row)

crewdb=# SELECT nextval('timesheet_timesheetid_seq');
 nextval 
---------
     419
(1 row)

crewdb=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
crewdb=# SELECT setval('timesheet_timesheetid_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(timesheetid)+1 FROM timesheet), 1), false);
 setval 
--------
    419
(1 row)

crewdb=# COMMIT;
COMMIT
```

Comment: I would say this is a bug, because it works if you only insert a single row instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `timesheetid` be an auto generated column, you should be able to simply omit it entirely from the insert's column list:

```
INSERT INTO timesheet (employeeid, date_linkid, employee_functionid, start_time,
    finish_time, note)
VALUES
    (1, 223, 1, '13:56:00', '16:40:00', NULL),
    (1, 223, 3, '18:10:00', '18:19:00', NULL);
```

Postgres will automatically generate the value for `timesheetid`.

Comment: Thanks mate, that did work. But I am still confused because all other tables accept insert commands with DEFAULT as primary key input.

Comment: @ChristianHick Yes, but in those other cases, are the columns you are using with `DEFAULT` also identity columns?

Comment: yes all are ` not null | generated always as identity`.

Comment: Do the other tables accept *multi-valued* insert statements with DEFAULT?